# WPF Creating DataTemplate for a control that doesn't have a DataTemplate property

Tags: wpf, slider, datatemplate

I'm creating a custom TickBar for a Slider. This CustomTickBar allows me to put different markers on the Slider. I'm gonna use the following model:

```
Interface IModel
{
   string Id;
}

Class Model1 : IModel
{
   string Id;
   string SomeProperty;
}

Class Model2 : IModel
{
   string Id;
   string SomeOtherProperty;
}
```

The idea is I provide a `List<IModel>` to this TickBar control and based on the type of `IModel` the marker icon would change; e.g. for `Model1` it would be a triangle and for `Model2` it would be a rectangle. I understand this would be possible using a DataTemplate. But WPF TickBar doesn't have a DataTemplate property. Now is there a way I can do this using a DataTemplate property and subclassing TickBar?

Note: I understand I can create custom tick using OnRender(), but I'm trying to check if there's a way to do it by writing as less code-behind as possible.

Comment: CustomTickBar can have custom markers which in turn can have DataTemplate property

Comment: @ASh could you give an example? Can't get my head around that.

Comment: @ASh If you had read the source code of `TickBar`, you would know that the visual of `TickBar` was drawn directly in `OnRender` method because it's depended on other properties dynamically. So `DataTemplate` would solve you problem, but override `OnRender` will.

Comment: What about the position of the ticks? would you like to define custom positions or somehow use the frequency of the TickBar ?

Comment: @Usama I would use custom positions. So they can appear anywhere on the slider.

Answer (score 0):

`TickBar` does not have default style, so it looks like using `OnRender` is the way they designed it.

Another solution I'm think about, would be:

1. Create custom control, you own TickBar. Maybe inherit from TickBar.
2. You can set your own style for this custom `TickBar`, even based on some of your model data.

Use `themes/generic.xaml` and this code to apply custom style for your control:

```
static void MyCustomTickBar() {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomTickBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomTickBar)));
}
```

3. Edit template of `Slider` and use you new TickBar instead of built in one.

[Here](https://paste.ofcode.org/mG3m22qPEJSuqzcR5cQDAB) is default template for Slider. I used style snooper to extract it. Sorry, I could not provide it in my answer, it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a style for the slider first.
e.g. Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBackground" Color="#FFE7EAEA"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBorder" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFAEB1AF" Offset="0.1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFAEB1AF" Offset=".9"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#009EFF" Stroke="#009EFF" Height="14" Width="14"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyCustomStyleForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top" Height="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom" Height="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" 
                                    Background="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBackground}"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBorder}"                                        
                                    BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="1"
                                    Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="10.0" Grid.Row="1" >
                                <Canvas Margin="-6,-2">
                                    <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Height="6.0"
                                               Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
                                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"
                                               StrokeThickness="2.0"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Border>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1"  >
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton  Style="{StaticResource  SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource CustomThumbForSlider}" Background="Black"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can then define a Slider which uses the style:

```
<Slider Name="CustomSlider" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyleForSlider}"/>
```

In order to change the style depending on some properties you can add a datatrigger. just replace the existing style with a new one:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Ellipse Fill="#009EFF" Stroke="#009EFF" Height="14" Width="14"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDifferent}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Ellipse Fill="#009055" Stroke="#009055" Height="14" Width="14"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This new Style is going to change the appearance when the datacontext of slider has a different value for the property "IsDifferent".

```
<Slider Name="CustomSlider" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyleForSlider}" DataContext="{Binding Path=MyContext}"/>
```

Of course it would be possible to replace the green ellipse with a different shape of your liking and also use a different property.

For the templating problem it is usally best to use a ControlTemplate or alternativly a ContentControl whose DataTemplate can be set freely and which will act as a parent for your own controls.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently tried overriding onrender for a custom slider myself and it's tricky. I wouldn't go that route.
I suggest you consider adding another control to hold the markers and make that match the height or width of your slider.
If your "ticks" at fixed then that could be just a uniformgrid containing paths and you use a resource to define their data using a DynamicResource geometry. You can switch out the geometry by merging different ones or datatemplate it.