How to hide or eliminate range markers in WPF slider
I am making a slider user control. I need the IsSelectionRangeEnable = "true" but I do not want the triangular markers that appear on the slider (shown in the image).
Fragment of slider with selection range

Is it possible to hide or eliminate those triangles?
I have tried looking at microsoft's custom slider templates and in stack overflow but haven't seen this adressed.

The selection-ticks are drawn in TickBar.OnRender method. So you will need to create custom TickBar, override OnRender method to remove the code for drawing selection-ticks and replace TickBars in Slider's Template with custom TickBars.

The idea on custom TickBar is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49216851/3137337
